# Verilog multiply routine outputting incorrect value

Tags: verilog, fpga

```
module multiply (input clk, //50mHz
    output reg [7:0] led);
                      
    reg [7:0] product=0;
    reg [3:0] ina=3;
    reg [3:0] inb=1;
    reg [32:0] cnt=0;
    
    always @ (posedge clk)
    begin
        product = mult(ina,inb);
        led <= product;
    end

    function [7:0] mult;
        input [3:0] a, b;
        reg [7:0] prod1;
        integer i;
    begin
        prod1 = 0;
        if (a[0] == 1)
            prod1 = b;
        else
            prod1 = 0;
        for (i=1;i<=3;i=i+1) begin
            if (a[i] == 1)
                prod1 = prod1 + b << i;
        end
        mult = prod1;
    end
    endfunction
endmodule
```

I am calling multiply on ina and inb; hard coded to 3 and 1.
The output I get is 00000100 = 4!
When I work it out on paper, I get 3.  But why do I get 4 when it is run on the fpga?

the multiply routine should do the following:

```
if (a[0] == 1)
    prod1 = b;
```

so prod1 is set to 00000001

next, the conditional in the loop executes only for i=1

```
prod1 = prod1 + b << 1
```

prod1 = 0000001 + 0010 = 00000011 = 3

Where am I going wrong here?  The FPGA is outputting 4.

Answer (score 3):

You should simulate your design first, then you can put `$display` statements in your `for` loop and immediately see what the problem is.

The expression `prod1 = prod1 + b << 1;` gets evaluated as `prod1 = (prod1 + b) << 1;` since `+` has higher precedence than `<<`.

You need to write it as `prod1 = prod1 + (b << 1);`